# Lines on projective hypersurfaces of large degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question refers to Exercise 11.3.J (c) from Ravi Vakil’s [The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf):

“Throughout, we work over an algebraically closed field. […]

If $d\geq n$, show that for “most hypersurfaces” $X$ of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$ (for all hypersurfaces whose corresponding point in the parameter space $\mathbb P^{{{n+d}\choose d}-1}$ — cf. Remark 4.5.3 and Exercise 8.2.K — lies in some nonempty Zariski-open subset), “most points $p\in X$” (all points in a nonempty dense Zariski-open subset of $X$) have no lines in $X$ passing through them. (Hint: first show that there is a single $p$ in a single $X$ contained in no line. Chevalley’s Theorem 7.4.2 may help.)“

- In (a) from the same exercise a method is explained to check if through a given point on $X$ with special (nice) coordinates there is a line contained in $X$: Essentially, one has to check $d$ many conditions.
- Part (b) is on the case $d\leq n-1$, where through each point of $X$ there does exist a line contained in $X$.
- Both (a) and (b) are clear to me. Also, (c) does at least seem plausible to me, as there are simply too many conditions for such lines to exist in general. I could imagine that for (c) one has to work with some “incidence scheme(s)”. **But how can (c) be solved rigorously?**
- What puzzles me furthermore is Vakil’s hint “first show that there is a single $p$ in a single $X$ contained in no line”: I think it is easy to prove this hint, but it is so much weaker than the full claim, therefore I do not understand how it could be helpful.
- Finally, Vakil gives another hint, namely that Chevalley's Theorem may help. Unfortunately, I do not see to what map Chevalley’s Theorem should be applied here.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p$ be the point $(1:0:\dots:0) \in \mathbb{P}^n$ and let $(x_0:x_1:\dots:x_n)$ be the homogeneous coordinates. The equation $f(x)$ of a hypersurface $X$ passing through $p$ can be written as
$$
f = x_0^{n-1}f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) + x_0^{n-2}f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) + \dots + f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n),
$$
where $f_i$ is a homogeneous polynoimal of degree $i$.
Lines through $p$ that lie on $X$ correspond to the solutions of the system of equations
$$
f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \dots = f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0.
$$
Now if $f_i$ are chosen generically, this system has no solutions. Indeed, for example you can take
$$
f_1 = x_1,
\quad 
f_2 = x_2^2,
\quad \dots, \quad 
f_n = x_n^n.
$$